# (urls.W005) URL namespace 'LnkIn' isn't unique.

Tags: python, django, windows

Hi I'm getting this error when doing my migrations or using the `python manage.py runserver` command.

```
(urls.W005) URL namespace 'LnkIn' isn't unique.You may not be able to reverse all URLs in this namespace.
```

This is how I have my urls.py inside my app directory (LnkIn).

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

app_name = 'LnkdIn'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^register/$', views.register, name='register'),
    url(r'^login_user/$', views.login_user, name='login_user'),
    url(r'^logout_user/$', views.logout_user, name='logout_user'),
    url(r'^(?P<user_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.profile, name='profile'),
    url(r'^(?P<song_id>[0-9]+)/favorite/$', views.favorite, name='favorite'),
    url(r'^trabajos/$', views.trabajos, name='trabajos'),
    url(r'^crear_oferta/$', views.crear_oferta, name='crear_oferta'),
    url(r'^(?P<user_id>[0-9]+)/create_trabajo/$', views.create_trabajo, name='create_trabajo'),
    url(r'^(?P<user_id>[0-9]+)/crear_amistad/$', views.crear_amistad, name='crear_amistad'),
    url(r'^(?P<user_id>[0-9]+)/delete_trabajo/(?P<trabajo_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.delete_trabajo, name='delete_trabajo'),
    url(r'^(?P<album_id>[0-9]+)/favorite_album/$', views.favorite_album, name='favorite_album'),
    url(r'^(?P<album_id>[0-9]+)/delete_album/$', views.delete_album, name='delete_album'),
]
```

And this is how I have my urls.py in my main directory.

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^LnkdIn/', include('LnkdIn.urls')),
    url(r'^', include('LnkdIn.urls')),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I really have no idea what could I've done wrong. I checked in my views and in my templates and everything seems to be fine, I don't seem to be having any typo on my urls. I've search but haven't find this error, I've seem similars one and they suggest to check not having mistakes in the urls.

I'm using Python 2.7 and Django 1.10.

Comment: You included `LnkdIn.urls` twice. While that works fine in one direction, it can not be reversed, since there would be two results. All functions based on the reverse mapper will not work as expected.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You are importing `LnkdIn.urls` twice to your application `urlpatterns`.

You should only do it once, so choose either one from the section below

```
url(r'^LnkdIn/', include('LnkdIn.urls')),
```

or

```
url(r'^', include('LnkdIn.urls')),
```

Comment: Is there a clean way to make multiple paths be resolved by one app's urls.py? What if I want `'MyApp/<int:MyApp_id>'` and `r'^'` to both be resolved using `MyApp`'s urls.py?

Comment: @MichaelHoffmann I would suggest using the base route (`r'^'`) in the main urlpatterns and prefix any URLs you want in the app urlpatterns with `'^LnkdIn/'`. If you're trying to route multiple URLs to the same endpoint with or without that "LnkdIn" segment, I'd discourage you, it's needlessly complicates your app's endpoints.

Comment: This solution not working when used ImageField  image does not loading