# Django: namespace isn't unique

Tags: django

In Django 1, I used to have the following URL mappings:

```
...
url(r'^main/', include('main.urls', namespace='main')),
url(r'.*', include('main.urls'))
```

The `r'.*'` mapping is always at the last line to take care of all kinds of URLs not mapped.

In Django 2, the following mappings are used instead:

```
path('main/', include('main.urls', namespace='main')),
re_path('.*', include('main.urls')),
```

Although it also works, yet Django complains:

```
?: (urls.W005) URL namespace 'main' isn't unique. You may not be able to reverse all URLs in this namespace
```

Giving the second mapping another namespace is not working. Any solutions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [(urls.W005) URL namespace 'LnkIn' isn't unique.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43713239/urls-w005-url-namespace-lnkin-isnt-unique)

Comment: Yes, the question is the same as that post, but I do need to include `'main.urls'` twice. Or, is there any way to direct *whatever* urls to the main page?

Comment: why don't you write a view that redirects .* to main/.*

Comment: But what would the url mapping to the view function be?

Comment: re_path('.*', views.redirect_view),

Comment: `re_path('.*', views.redirect_view)` works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try writing a view to redirect to main/ and then include the view in your urls:

```
re_path('.*', views.redirect_view)
```

Answer (score 0):

In that case you can use `django.views.generic.base.RedirectView` to simply redirect to the said url without importing it twice.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('main', include('main.urls')),
    re_path('.*', RedirectView.as_view(url='main/your_default_url_in_main_url'), name='main'),
]
```

Try to remove the trailing slash of `'main/'` and change to `'main'`.

Note: If your `main.urls` looks like this

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('/whatever1', view1), 
    path('/whatever2', view2), 
]
```

You have to pick where to redirect the default view by supplying `RedirectView.as_view(url='main/whatever1')` to redirect to `view1` as default. use `'main/whatever2'` to redirect to `view2` as default

reference: [RedirectView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/base/#redirectview)

Comment: This results in the url: `localhost:8000/main/main/main/...`

Comment: remove `name='main'`

Comment: Removing `name='main'` does not work. The url is still changed to `localhost:8000/main/main/main/...`

Comment: If I enter `localhost:8000/whatever/`, the console shows `GET /whatever/`, `GET /whatever/main/`, `GET /whatever/main/main/`, `GET /whatever/main/main/main/` ... It goes on and on.

Comment: Still not working, same error (repeated redirection).

Comment: Again i updated the answer `main/` of redirectview url does not match any url in your main.urls. you have to explicitly specify it to work

Comment: Check if there is a duplicate name which might be rising the conflict. Otherwise the above recommendations should work just fine.